# Class 'Anonymous class derived from AdListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onLoggingImpressionMethod(Ad)'

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

Error:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from AdListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onLoggingImpressionMethod(Ad)' in 'AdListener'

Here is my code:

```
    private void setUpFacebookAD() {
        //AdSettings.addTestDevice("ae869b4a0e40ebbea07dafaabd9690aa");
        mFBNativeAd = new NativeAd(context, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        mFBNativeAd.setAdListener(new com.facebook.ads.AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
                // Ad error callback
                Log.i("fb native ad","on Error" + " "+ error.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Ad loaded callback
                Log.i("FB native ad ", "On Ad loaded");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
                Log.i("FB natvie Ad" , "onAd clicked");
            }
        });
        mFBNativeAd.loadAd(NativeAd.MediaCacheFlag.ALL);
    }
```

The com.facebook.ads.AdListener is red color underlined. I tried reduced it to AdListener only but still getting error. It only happened after I upgraded the jdk version and the location of JDK. Before the upgrade the code is working. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what you must do to fix the problem: implement a method with the signature `'onLoggingImpressionMethod(Ad)`. If you move the caret to the  line that says `new com.facebook.ads.AdListener()`, you can press Alt-Enter and select from the popup menu to automatically insert this method for you.